# How can I create a map with chars as key values and arrays of strings as mapped values - arrays must be of different length?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

I am unsure of the syntax required to make a map where key values are type char and mapped values are type string array. The arrays need to be different lengths.
Something like:

```
map <char, string> backtranslate;
backtranslate['M'] = {"ATG"};
backtranslate['H'] = {"CAT", "CAC"}
```

Please could someone specify and explain the correct syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably meant something like `map <char, vector<string>> backtranslate;`

Comment: There is also `std::multimap`

Comment: So, vector is required for map type, rather than arrays? Or is vector required if one wished to make a string "array"?

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak Your sample code shows, that you want to map a list of `string` values with a `char`, that's usually represented with a `std::vector<std::string>` for the list of `string` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
map<char,vector<string>> backtranslate;
backtranslate['M'].push_back("ATG");
backtranslate['H'].push_back("CAT");
backtranslate['H'].push_back("CAC");
```

Comment: Should be worth mentioning [`std::initializer_list<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Comment: So, you can keep adding string elements using `push_back` and they will be appended to the vector mapped to the specific key chosen inside `['']`?

Comment: Many thanks,I forget how helpful this community is :)

Comment: @KarimBENHDECH: There's a song named "before you accuse me, take a look at yourself". This code works fine in C++, which is the language that the question is tagged under. Your code might be working correctly (I haven't tested it), but it's written in Java, which makes your answer irrelevant to the question at hand!

Comment: Sincerely sorry. I thought i was in java section :)

Comment: @KarimBENHDECH: No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

In Map, you can put as key or value, everything extends Object. But type argument cannot be of primitive type, char is a primitive Type. In place of char ou can use the type String.

Map begin by uppercase.

For add an element in Map, the method "put" exist.

A solution :

```
 Map<String, String[]> backtranslate = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
 backtranslate.put("M", new String[]{"ATG"});
 backtranslate.put("H", new String[]{"CAT", "CAC"});
```

Or (I prefer List, more easy to manipulate) :

```
Map<String, List<String>> backtranslate = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
backtranslate.put("M", Arrays.asList("ATG"));
backtranslate.put("H", Arrays.asList("CAT", "CAC"));
```

Comment: This code looks like Java. The question is tagged C++.

Comment: Did I do something wrong here? As in, why is java being given as solutions? Have I caused confusion by not tagging the question in C++ section correctly?